# How to access elements in Android spinner using Appium?

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

I'm writing automation tests for Android using Appium. There is a form in the app where you select gender. When you press gender field a spinner comes out for you to select a gender. But I can't see the spinner or it's options in the Appium's app source list. I have to see their selectors to use it in code.

[image]

It looks like this in Android Studio's layout inspector:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public void testExample(){
WebElement spinner=driver.findElement(By.id(“android:id/text1”));
spinner.click();
driver.scrollToExact(“India”);
WebElement optionIndia=driver.findElement(By.name(“India”));
optionIndia.click();
}
```

Comment: I tried to find elements by id and by name but it can't find it. I also tried getPageSource but the spinner menu is not listed there either.

Comment: @Serra : ask developer to make visible id and other attributes.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the ids. The layout inspector shows the spinner as a different layout. It is not listed in the base layout.

Comment: must be layout of other screen or spinner could be drawable. deawable element has no view

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using touchPerform with 'press' and 'release'. I tried before with touchAction and 'tap' but that didn't work.